# Xcode Segue View Controller Right to left without UINavigation

Tags: ios, segue, xcode7

I want to transition my View Controller Right to Left (just like a Navigation Controller does IT) BUT without a UINavigationController embedded. I'm using Xcode 7 and the standard Segue seems to not have this option. Any guidance is VERY much welcome!!!

Comment: Why? It's not that hard to embed a view controller in a navigation controller. If you don't want the navigation bar you can just hide it.

Comment: using storyboard transition, I need it to use the right-left transition as it indicates a phase. currently, the view comes from bottom-top which deprecates the transition process. i have Xcode 7 iOS 9... No matter what default transition i use, it goes from Bottom-top... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be a hack, you can do this:

```
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.3;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;
[self.view.window.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];

[self presentModalViewController:viewCtrl animated:NO];
```

You should really just use a navigation controller or write a custom transition animation see [here](https://github.com/soleares/SOLPresentingFun) for a project that does the animation you want.

```
let transition = CATransition()
transition.duration = 0.3
transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
transition.type = kCATransitionPush
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight

self.view.window?.layer.addAnimation(transition,forKey:nil)
self.presentViewController(viewCtrl, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

if you need it in Swift.

Comment: Hello. Sorry for the late Reply. I need to present a right-left segue but prevent the user from segue back to the previous view. This is for transactions that should not segue back to the previous screen :)

Comment: I tried the transition (objective-c) and the animation is a bit jerky.. I'm using '    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueMe" sender:nil];' also, presentModalViewController is already deprecated.

Comment: Embed the presenting view controller in a navigation controller in the storyboard by clicking on the view controller then click editor->embed in->navigation controller.  In viewDidLoad say self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=YES;.  Then create a show segue to the view controller you want to presented "from right to left."